# Is it true, for every set $A$ and relation R, that $A \subseteq R^{-1}[R[A]]$?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Here, $R[X] = \{ y \in ran(R): \exists x \in A (\langle x, y \rangle \in R)\}$ and $R^{-1}[X] = \{ x \in dom(R): \exists y \in X( \langle x, y \rangle \in R)\}$.

It seems to me that it is not true. Taking $R = \{\langle a, b \rangle\}$ and $A = \{ 1\}$, then $R[A] = \emptyset$, and $R^{-1}[R[A]] = R^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$ - but $A \not \subseteq \emptyset$. However, I'm insecure about my reasoning, because an exercise from an assignement I'm helping a friend with asked us to prove that $A \subseteq R^{-1}[R[A]]$.

Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: (Deleted my earlier incorrect comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. An even simpler counter-example to the claim is to take $R = \emptyset$ and $A \neq \emptyset$.